# Custom Android Bottom Menu Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I went through many questions regarding making bottom bar but my my question is a bit different.I want to make this.

bottom menu:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdB2Q.png]

Now the thing is, the menu is not static.It's items can vary depending upon user's choice.So, I have to make it dynamic. What's the best approach to achieve this?
Also, I'm not sure how do I make that curved outline at the center item.I'm thinking that I should do it programmatically.Any suggestions are welcome.Even better if you can share code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to create Navigation bar, it will surly create view that you show us in image.

https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Bottom menu is now an official navigation view according to the [official documentation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-usage) but as far as I know, there is no native component available yet to implement that.

In my opinion, your best bet is to try customizing the following library created by Iiro Krankka (http://github.com/roughike):

[BottomBar](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13473164)

Comment: @Lal I understand your point but in this case the solution is a library and I don't see how I could add that in a simple answer.

Comment: In the latest version (v25) of design support library is [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) that is ready to use component to build bottom bar.